# HTML Internal link not working as expected

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

This seems like a trivial question but for some reason, I can't get an internal link to work properly.

I have 2 internal links (shown in the screenshots) on this page - https://www.top10metalbazookas.gq/products/elevar-arc-racer-us

When I click on this link it scrolls down to the correct section on the page

[image: Internal link works here]

However, when I click on this link, nothing happens

[image: Internal link does not work here]

For reference, the `href` attributes for both `a` tags have this as the ID.

```
#shopify-section-es-us-product-template-reviews
```

Is this some event propagation issue or some other kind of CSS bug or am I doing something silly here?

Comment: if you set `.es-price-row-reviews a{display:block;}` it'll work just fine

Comment: @RamondeVries when I do this, it begins to scroll but then goes back to the top of the page.

Comment: Something weird is actually happening. If I click on `.review` then it works fine but if I click on the `span` tag inside it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are your ids not unique in the page? If so, that's probably your problem - an HTML document with duplicate ids is not a valid document.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this through jQuery for now. Since it's urgent. But I don't think it's the best option. If anyone has a hunch as to why the simple internal scrolling didn't work, please let me know.

This is how I did it:

```
function(t) {
  t.preventDefault();
  var e = $(this).attr('href');
  $(e).trigger('click'), setTimeout(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(e).offset().top - 100
      },
      800,
      'swing'
    );
  }, 300);
}
```